# Domain user with PIN login

Tags: windows-10, passwords, active-directory

I have a Windows 10 user who has an SBS11 domain account and has his computer configured to log in with a PIN.  He wants to change the domain password.  I am concerned that if I change that password from ADUC, his Windows profile on that Windows 10 box will become inaccessible as the PIN will be tied to his old password and not be updated.  How do I make sure this does not happen?  In other words, how can I update his password and make sure that the PIN wil still log him into his Windows profile on this machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't this user just change their own user profile?  Any event, their password and pin are indeed separate, changing one should not effect the other.  If the user is using EFS they should change their own password.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to your context, but the article
[Windows Hello and password changes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-and-password-changes)
may also pertain for other uses than Windows Hello and Microsoft accounts.

It says this:

> Let's suppose that you have set up a PIN for your Microsoft account on
>   Device A. You use your PIN to sign in on Device A and then change the
>   password for your Microsoft account. Because you were using Device A
>   when you changed your password, the PIN on Device A will continue to
>   work with no other action on your part.
>
> Suppose instead that you sign in on Device B and change your password
>   for your Microsoft account. The next time that you try to sign in on
>   Device A using your PIN, sign-in will fail because the account
>   credentials that Hello on Device A knows will be outdated.

The problem is easily solved according to the article:

> 1. When you try to sign in using your PIN or biometric, you will see the following message: *Your password was changed on a different
>      device. You must sign in to this device once with your new password,
>      and then you can sign in with your PIN*.
> 2. Click OK.
> 3. Click Sign-in options.
> 4. Click the Password button.
> 5. Sign in with new password.
> 6. The next time that you sign in, you can select Sign-in options and then select PIN to resume using your PIN.